# Move Files to a Backup Folder every first in the month and Zip the Files

Tags: powershell, backup, powershell-ise, getdate

I have never worked with powershell and I only need a program that is always run at the beginning of the month

What should the program do?

At the beginning of the month it should move all data except for the last month to another folder and zip it there to save storage space.

to my question i have (-31 days) but not every month has 31 days how could i solve it or does it fit like that?

I'm sorry if I explained something wrong here, please let me know.

```
foreach ($kunde in (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordneralt" -Exclude *.pdf , *.jpeg, *.png, *.gif ))
{
       $dirname = $kunde.name 
            for ($i=0; $i -lt $dirname.length; $i++)
                {
                    $dirbackup = $dirname + "BP"
                    get-childitem -Path "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordneralt\$dirname\ARCHIV" |
                    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} | 
                    move-item -destination "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordnerneu\$dirbackup"
                }
                    

            $dirdate = get-date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd' 
            $backupname = $dirdate + "__" +  $dirname

                    Compress-Archive -Path "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordnerneu\$dirbackup" -DestinationPath "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordnerneu\$dirbackup\$backupname"
                    Remove-Item "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordnerneu\$dirbackup" -Recurse -Include *.pdf -force
}
```

i was searching for ideas but i didnt find nothing

Comment: What's your actual question? You will always have the first of a given month on the **1st** of the month. If you want to determine if something is from the same month you simply use the month as criteria. You may inspect the output of `Get-Date | fl *` to have an idea what you can use.

Comment: Try (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)  this will get the same day of the previous month.  On the 1st, it will get the 1st day of the previous month.

Comment: You can get the number of days in the current month using `[DateTime]::DaysInMonth((Get-Date).Year, (Get-Date).Month)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys!

the program will get executed every first of the month and i managed it like that. that worked for me!

```
$tage =(Get-Date).adddays(-1).day +1 #  value of days from month before
                
                $dirbackup = $dirname + "BP"
                get-childitem -Path "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordneralt\$dirname\ARCHIV" | 
                where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$tage)} | 
                move-item -destination "C:\Users\kaar\Desktop\Ordnerneu\Temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#code is to get the first date of every month
$firstday=get-date -Day 1
```

Alternative approach is to schedule your script in Task Scheduler to trigger the PowerShell script on 1st of every month at specified time.
Reference [link](https://o365reports.com/2019/08/02/schedule-powershell-script-task-scheduler/) to create a new task in task scheduler

Comment: Why so complicated? A simple `Get-Date -Day 1` would give you the first of the current month. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that was not the question sorry my fault.. 
i will execute the programm with a task Scheduler the question i have is i have a "get-date" and then -31 days but let's assume it's february then it's only 28 days or am i understanding something wrong and that makes no difference or no sense and i can use -31..

Comment: I think you're overvcopmplicating this. If you have a given date and you want to get the the first day of the same month you *extract* the month from the given date and built the desired date with the day 1 and the month you just extracted. ;-)

Comment: @Neta68, that's ok. Kindly look into my answer... Irrespective of no of days, you will get the 1st day of every month

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you can get the number of days in the current month with

```
$today = Get-Date
$nDays = [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($today.Year, $today.Month)
# set to midnight so it is independent of the actual time the script runs
$refDate = $today.AddDays(-$nDays).Date
```

Then just use that in your Where-Object clause:

```
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate}
```